# StrongOD Driver missing

Tags: ollydbg, driver

Rather short question.

So i've taken to using StrongOD for Ollydbg and I noticed that the fengyue0.sys doesn't exist, I had googled around and restarted my computer in hopes it would be created, yet no dice.

Does anyone know how to aquire this?

Comment: You may use a better stealth plugin *[TitanHide](https://bitbucket.org/mrexodia/titanhide)* for kernel mode or *[ScyllaHide](https://bitbucket.org/NtQuery/scyllahide)* for user mode. They have all batteries included.